# get the custom post type title/name

Tags: custom-post-types, php, archives, custom-post-type-archives, wp-get-archives

I'm using a custom post type and use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-custom-post-type-archive/) to display my custom post type's archives, does anyone knows how to display my custom post type's name/title to the archive.php?

Below is the archive.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
 <!-- **Main - Starts** --> 
<div id="main">
    <div class="parallax full-width-bg" style="background: #ffffff;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-title">
                <h1><?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' ); ?></h1>
                <p style="color:#dddddd;font-size:13px;font-style:italic;margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;"><?php the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' ); ?></p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Primary Starts -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <section id="primary" class="with-right-sidebar page-with-sidebar">
            <div class="dt-sc-margin30"></div>
             <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content-archive', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;?>
            <div class="dt-sc-margin80"></div>
            <div class="dt-sc-margin80"></div>
        </section> <!-- **Primary - Ends** -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <?php else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        endif; ?>  
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
wp_footer();
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`post_type_archive_title( $prefix = '', $display = true )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_type_archive_title/):

```
<h1><?php post_type_archive_title() ?></h1>
```